# Source map to files outside public directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gruntjs, source-maps

I have a file structure like this:

```
/server/
 - package.json
 - node_modules/
 - Gruntfile.js
/public/
 - index.html
 - assets/
```

When in `/server` I run `npm install`, which downloads things like `Angular` into `/server/node_modules`.

I then run the `Gruntfile.js` which looks like this:

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({

    //concat js
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';',
        sourceMap: true
      },
      lib: {
        src: [
          './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
          './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',
          './node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'
        ],
        dest: '../public/assets/build/lib/lib.min.js'
      }
    },

    //minify js
    uglify: {
      options: {
        mange: true,
        compress: true,
        sourceMap: true
      },
      lib: {
        src: '<%= concat.lib.dest %>',
        dest: '<%= concat.lib.dest %>'
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat', 'uglify']);
```

The grunt file works as expected to concat and minify the Angular modules with a source map. The problem is that the domain name points to the public directory, but the source map wants to point to the Angular source code in the server directory, which I don't think will work.

How do I get around this problem? Do I have to have the node_modules in the root of the public directory? I'd rather not have any precompiled code in the public directory if possible, the reason being that when I put the site live, I can simply FTP the public directory and ignore the server, reducing unnecessary bulk.